# DocuSign Python SDK - Retrieve newly generated document to sign?

Tags: django, python-3.x, docusignapi

I am trying to develop a web app for my company that will generate a pdf to be signed by one user. The user enters information into a form, and then, using weasyprint, an html file that I've formatted generates a pdf containing the user information. Finally, using docusign's python SDK, I want a field that requires a signature to be able to be signed by the user. Everything up until the docusign bit is working.

The following is the code I'm currently using, based on the example by @Lee.

```
def Signview(request):
    myobject = MYOBJECT.objects.filter().order_by('-id')[0]
    username = "myUsername"
    integrator_key = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
    base_url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
    oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com"
    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8000/path/to/redirect/uri"
    private_key_filename = "path/to/pKey.txt"
    user_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    client_user_id = 'Your System ID' #This is the actual string I'm using

    # Add a recipient to sign the document
    signer = docusign.Signer()
    signer.email = myobject.email #myobject is a model from my database, containing this information.
    signer.name = myobject.name
    signer.recipient_id = '1'
    signer.client_user_id = client_user_id

    sign_here = docusign.SignHere()
    sign_here.document_id = '1'
    sign_here.recipient_id = '1'
    sign_here.anchor_case_sensitive = 'true'
    sign_here.anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left'
    sign_here.anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false'
    sign_here.anchor_match_whole_word = 'true'

    sign_here.anchor_string = 'Sign Here'
    sign_here.anchor_units = 'cms'
    sign_here.anchor_x_offset = '0'
    sign_here.anchor_y_offset = '0'
    sign_here.tab_label = 'sign_here'
    tabs = docusign.Tabs()
    tabs.sign_here_tabs = [sign_here]

    # Create a signers list, attach tabs to signer, append signer to signers.
    # Attach signers to recipients objects
    signers = []
    tabs = tabs
    signer.tabs = tabs
    signers.append(signer)
    recipients = docusign.Recipients()
    recipients.signers = signers

    # Create an envelope to be signed
    envelope_definition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition()
    envelope_definition.email_subject = 'My email subject'
    envelope_definition.email_blurb = 'My email blurb.'

    # Add a document to the envelope_definition
    pdfpath = "path/to/mypdf.pdf"
    with open(pdfpath, 'rb') as signfile:
        file_data = signfile.read()
        doc = docusign.Document()
        base64_doc = base64.b64encode(file_data).decode('utf-8')
        doc.document_base64 = base64_doc
        doc.name = "mypdf_signed.pdf"
        doc.document_id = '1'
        envelope_definition.documents = [doc]
        signfile.close()
    envelope_definition.recipients = recipients
    envelope_definition.status = 'sent'

    api_client = docusign.ApiClient(base_url)

    oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)
    print(oauth_login_url)

    api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
    docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

    auth_api = AuthenticationApi()
    envelopes_api = Envelopes_Api()

    try: #login here via code
        login_infoi = auth_api.login()
        login_accounts = login_info.login_accoutns
        base_url, _ = login_accounts[0].base_url.split('/v2')
        api_client.host = base_url
        docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

        envelope_summary = envelopes_api.create_envelope(login_accounts[0].account_id, envelope_definition = envelope_definition)

        print(envelope_summary)
    except ApiException as e:
        raise Exception("Exception when calling DocuSign API: %s" % e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The following is the error that I'm receiving (Bad Request API Exception):

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/createquote/genloa/sign/

Django Version: 2.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['createquote',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\users\wkstat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\users\wkstat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\users\wkstat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\wkstat\Desktop\Development\LNQuoteTool\createquote\views.py" in Signview
  141.  api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)

File "C:\users\wkstat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\api_client.py" in configure_jwt_authorization_flow
  126.                                 post_params=self.sanitize_for_serialization({"assertion": assertion, "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"}))

File "C:\users\wkstat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\api_client.py" in request
  430.                                          body=body)

File "C:\users\wkstat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\rest.py" in POST
  244.                             body=body)

File "C:\users\wkstat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\rest.py" in request
  200.             raise ApiException(http_resp=r)

Exception Type: ApiException at /createquote/genloa/sign/
Exception Value: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': 'ec891538-ed2f-4250-bc50-966c96065052', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'DA1DFE4', 'Date': 'Tue, 31 Jul 2018 18:07:22 GMT', 'Content-Length': '11'})
HTTP response body: b'Bad Request'
```

I have added the Redirect URI to my docusign admin account. I don't understand what it is I'm doing wrong.

Below are a couple of requested variables:

**oauth_base_url**: account-d.docusign.com

**oauth_login_url**: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=signature%20impersonation&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fcreatequote%2Fgenloa%2Fsign%2F

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please EDIT your question to add additional information: what happened? Did you get an error message? (If so, please include the message.)

Comment: Thank you, @LarryK! Truthfully, I haven't run this code just yet. I will do my best to finish putting this together, and add the information on what happens. Moreover, I'm just trying to understand how the variables are meant to be used. I have been reading through the documentation, and I feel like I still don't really understand what is supposed to be what. 

When I run the program, after a form that I created is filled out, a PDF of a specific form is created. I'm wanting to know how to use that newly generated PDF to get signed through this. Is that what the template is?

Comment: Moreover, I just really don't understand what the difference between "envelope" and "template" is, and I don't feel like it's made obvious through the wording in the documentation that I've read.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I tried to integrated docusign with our system. First, I will suggest you to check the docusign documents of C# version which is better documented then the python one. [Github Repo](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/tree/master/sdk/docs). Also, please check the python sdk repo to see the examples.

To answer your question, I will post our implementation with **simplified** code here. In our implementation, we didn't implement the template api. We just generate our own pdf file and **Attach** the PDF as **Document** to the **Envelope Definition**. Also, you need to add recipients information(including the tabs and signers) and notification information to the definition. **Basically, most parameters for the envelope definition are optional, you need to figure out what you needs to use them.** After that, you could use the envelope definition to create the envelope.

Please notice that, after these process, you will get an **envelope id**. You may want to change the envelope status to 'sent' to send it through docusign. Or, if you want to integrate it with your app, you could create a docusign.RecipientViewRequest() to get the temporary url which the signer could use it to open a docusign page and sign the contract.

```
def create_envelope(file_data, other_info):
    ## .....
    ## file_data is the pdf data
    envelope_definition = create_envelope_definition(file_data, other_info)
    envelope_id = docusign_create_envelope(envelope_definition)
    ## .....

def create_envelope_definition(file_data, other_info):

    envelope_definition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition()
    envelope_definition.email_subject = 'your email subject'
    envelope_definition.email_blurb = 'your email message here'

    # add a document to the envelope
    doc = docusign_parameter_document(file_data)
    envelope_definition.documents = [doc]

    # Add recipients to sign the document
    recipients = docusign_parameter_recipients(other_info['recipients_info'])

    envelope_definition.recipients = recipients
    envelope_definition.status = 'your init envelope status' # if you want to send it when you create the envelope instantly, set it to sent
    envelope_definition.event_notification = docusign_parameter_event_notification()

    envelope_definition.notification = docusign_parameter_notification(other_info['notification_setting'])

    return envelope_definition

def docusign_parameter_document(file_data):
    doc = docusign.Document()
    base64_doc = base64.b64encode(file_data).decode("utf-8")
    doc.document_base64 = base64_doc
    doc.name = 'your file name'
    doc.document_id = '1'
    return doc

def docusign_parameter_recipients(other_info):
    signers = []
    for e in other_info.contract_signers:
        signer = docusign_parameter_signer(e)
        tabs = docusign_parameter_tabs(other_info, e)
        signer.tabs = tabs
        signers.append(signer)

    recipients = docusign.Recipients()
    recipients.signers = signers
    return recipients


def docusign_parameter_signer(....):
    signer = docusign.Signer()
    signer.email = 'your signer email'
    signer.name = 'your signer name'
    signer.recipient_id = '1' 
    client_user_id = 'your local system id'
    signer.client_user_id = client_user_id
    return signer

def docusign_parameter_tabs(contract_signer):
    sign_here = docusign.SignHere()
    sign_here.document_id = '1'
    sign_here.recipient_id = '1' # notice: here i just simply set up it as 1, after the envelope created, you could retrieve the actual id by using envelopes_api.list_recipients
    sign_here.anchor_case_sensitive = 'true'
    sign_here.anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left'
    sign_here.anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false'
    sign_here.anchor_match_whole_word = 'true'
    sign_here.anchor_string = 'your placeholder string' # you need to use the string to place your sign here tab, otherwise, you need to set up a x,y coordinate to place the tab
    sign_here.anchor_units = 'cms'
    sign_here.anchor_x_offset = '0'
    sign_here.anchor_y_offset = '0'
    sign_here.tab_label = 'sign_here'
    tabs = docusign.Tabs()
    tabs.sign_here_tabs = [sign_here]
    return tabs

def docusign_parameter_event_notification():
    ## return a EventNotification() object

def docusign_parameter_notification(contract):
    ## return a Notification() object

def docusign_create_envelope(envelope_definition):
    ##......some variable declarations here

    api_client = docusign_auth(base_url, integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url, private_key_filename, user_id)

    auth_api = AuthenticationApi()
    envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi()

    try:
        ## atuh......
        envelope_summary = envelopes_api.create_envelope(login_accounts[0].account_id,
                                                         envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
        return envelope_summary.envelope_id
    except ApiException as e:
        raise Exception("Exception when calling DocuSign API: %s" % e)

def docusign_auth(base_url, integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url, private_key_filename, user_id):
    api_client = docusign.ApiClient(base_url)
    api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
    docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client
    return docusign.configuration.api_client
```

If you have any questions, please leave comments below. I will try to solve that. Hope it helps.

---

**EDITED**
Question: How to access the pdf file and send it through docusign?

If you know the path(including the file name and extension) of your pdf file. Then, you just need to use the code below:

```
with open(filepath, "rb") as fileobj: 
    file_data = fileobj.read()
```

to get the pdf file data as a variable file_data. 
Then, please notice the function

```
docusign_parameter_document()
```

In the function, you need this line

```
base64_doc = base64.b64encode(file_data).decode("utf-8")
```

to pass the file_data variable into the function and get the base64 encoded data. And finally, you could attach the base64_doc to the [Document](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/docs/Document.md) object.

---

**EDITED** A SHORT WORKING EXAMPLE for ＤＥＶＥＬＯＰＭＥＮＴ MODE

```
def test(): 
    username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    integrator_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    # Do not change here if your are using development env
    base_url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
    # Do not change here if your are using development env
    oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com"
    redirect_uri = "https://xxxxxx.xx"

    # Path to your test key file
    private_key_filename = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/test_private_key.txt"

    # Same as your username
    user_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    # Add a recipient to sign the document
    signer = docusign.Signer()
    signer.email = 'xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com'
    signer.name = 'your name'
    signer.recipient_id = '1'
    client_user_id = '1'
    signer.client_user_id = client_user_id

    # Create a SignHere tab somewhere on the document for the signer to sign
    sign_here = docusign.SignHere()
    sign_here.document_id = '1'
    sign_here.recipient_id = '1'
    sign_here.anchor_case_sensitive = 'true'
    sign_here.anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left'
    sign_here.anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false'
    sign_here.anchor_match_whole_word = 'true'

    ############################################################################## 
    #Please notice that, the string 'Sign Here' need to be shown in your pdf file#
    ############################################################################## 
    sign_here.anchor_string = 'Sign Here'
    sign_here.anchor_units = 'cms'
    sign_here.anchor_x_offset = '0'
    sign_here.anchor_y_offset = '0'
    sign_here.tab_label = 'sign_here'
    tabs = docusign.Tabs()
    tabs.sign_here_tabs = [sign_here]


    # Create a signers list, attach tabs to signer, append signer to singers
    # attach signers to recipients object
    signers = []
    tabs = tabs
    signer.tabs = tabs
    signers.append(signer)
    recipients = docusign.Recipients()
    recipients.signers = signers

    # Create an envelope to be signed
    envelope_definition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition()
    envelope_definition.email_subject = 'mysubject'
    envelope_definition.email_blurb = 'myblurb'

    # add a document to the envelope_definition
    pdfpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/blank1.pdf"
    with open(pdfpath, 'rb') as signfile:
        file_data = signfile.read()
        doc = docusign.Document()
        base64_doc = base64.b64encode(file_data).decode('utf-8')
        doc.document_base64 = base64_doc
        doc.name = 'myDoc'
        doc.document_id = '1'
        envelope_definition.documents = [doc]
        signfile.close()
    envelope_definition.recipients = recipients
    envelope_definition.status = 'sent'
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print(cwd)

    api_client = docusign.ApiClient(base_url)

    ### You need open your browser, visit the url onece and approve
    oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)

    api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
    docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

    auth_api = AuthenticationApi()
    envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi()

    try:
        ############################################
        # Notice: you need login here via your code here
        ############################################
        login_info = auth_api.login()
        login_accounts = login_info.login_accounts
        base_url, _ = login_accounts[0].base_url.split('/v2')
        api_client.host = base_url
        docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

        envelope_summary = envelopes_api.create_envelope(login_accounts[0].account_id,
                                                         envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
        print(envelope_summary)
    except ApiException as e:
        raise Exception("Exception when calling DocuSign API: %s" % e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: I see, this looks very helpful! I'll take a look at this and see if I can identify the methods that will work in my project.

As far as my other attempts have gone, I have another thread posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487926/maxretryerror-with-docusign-in-django

Of course, I will also look into the C# implementation, as I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong as far as the python SDK goes. Thank you so much for your time and helpfulness! :)

Comment: As far as implementation goes, I do have a couple of questions:

  - Tabs: Are these necessary? From what I've read in the reference; "Custom Tabs enable accounts to have one or more pre-configured (custom) tabs. Custom tabs save time when users are tagging documents since the users don't have to manually set the tabs' parameters.

This category enables custom tabs to be managed programmatically, including creation, deletion, etc." I don't quite understand, from reading this, why they are necessary. What exactly do they do?

Comment: - Notifications/EventNotifications: Are these necessary? As my workflow goes, a user fills out a form that generates a PDF that is saved into a model in my database. After it is saved, I am attempting to take that file from the database, and use docusign to get it signed. There will only ever be one user to sign at a time, and I intend to have an email address from my company receive the email with the signed document, so if notifications aren't necessary, I would rather not use them.

Also, as far as a lot of these functions go, I am planning on condensing them into one function.

Comment: Hi, @JCoder96. I'm sorry for the confusion. To clarify, the Notification/EventNotifications are optional. The **EventNotification** just acts as a webhook configuration. So, if you set up a listener on your server, it would be notified when the customer completes the signature. The **Notification** could be used to set up expiration days and reminders for the contract. (continued in the next comment)

Comment: The **Tabs**, however, is necessary in your case since you need to add a sign_here tab on your pdf. The complete process is: 1, use docusign.SignHere() to create a **sign_here** object; 2, use docusign.Tabs() to create a **tabs** object; 3, attach **sign_here** as a list [sign_here]  to **tabs.sign_here_tabs**;  4, use docusign.Signer() to create a **signer** object; 5, attach the **tabs** object to signer.tabs; 6, use docusign.Recipients() to create a **recipients** object and attach **signer** (put the objects into a list) to the recipients.signers. (continued in the next comment)

Comment: 7. finally, you could attach the **recipients** to the envelope_definition.recipients. |||| Besides, just for your information, the Tabs could also be used for adding text input, timestamp and etc to the document you provided so the user could input their data into the tabs during the signing process.

Comment: Hi, @JCoder96 I am glad it helps. To answer your question, I suppose you know the path(including the file name and extension) of your pdf file. Then, you just need to use  **with open(filepath, "rb") as fileobj: file_data = fileobj.read()** to get the pdf file data as a variable **file_data**.  Then, please notice the function docusign_parameter_document(). In the function,  you need this line **base64_doc = base64.b64encode(file_data).decode("utf-8")** to pass the file_data variable into the function and get the base64 encoded data.

Comment: Finally, you can use **doc.document_base64 = base64_doc** to attach the file data to the Document object.

Comment: I feel like I'm almost there. After making the changes, my error is 'name "docusign_auth" is not defined'. Following the example that was listed in the documentation, I have all of the necessary modules currently imported into my project. Which module contains "docusign_auth"?

Comment: I'm sorry. docusign_auth is just my own function. It returns docusign.configuration.api_client. I have added the code in the original answer.

Comment: Hmm... Okay, so I've added the lines from your docusign_auth, and that seems to all be well. The variable "user_id", which is assigned as "your local system id". I've set this as my username on this device, that being 'wkstat'. That is the user I log in to to do my work. Is this correct? Also, I have the following error now:

Comment: Exception Value: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': '-1', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '4f983b3d-0fe4-4105-9ba9-67ec95fc4bb1', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block; report=/client-errors/xss',

Comment: 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'CH3DFE181', 'Date': 'Fri, 27 Jul 2018 15:17:09 GMT', 'Content-Length': '27'})
HTTP response body: b'{"error":"invalid_request"}'

Comment: It should be your docusign user id which is provided in your docusign admin dashboard. You could refer your own code at the top of your question about how to set up docusign api client. I think the code example is pretty enough to do that. The **"your local system id"** is assigned to **client_user_id** not **user_id**. The **client_user_id** is used for identifying the signer in your local system.

Comment: Ah, so as far as the client_user_id is concerned, this could just be an arbitrary name that I give them? I have also edited the user_id to be the api user_id listed under the admin page. This seems to have changed the error that I'm receiving a bit, but I'm still receiving a "bad request" error.

Comment: Have you go through the authentication process? For me, I choose the service integration. Document is here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken And, code example is on the same page of the python sdk repo in the usage section. https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client I suggest you to read the document and try to understand the oauth process. Baiscally, you need to use the line **oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)** to get a url and complete the one-time authentication.

Comment: I noticed that you didn't customize your own base_url and redirect_uri. You need to add your own site to the docusign admin dashboard(the integrator key part) and assign  your own site to the two variable. Also, for security reason, please hide your integrator key and user_id in your quesiton.

Comment: Regarding the authentication process, there's a couple of things I don't quite understand from reading the links you sent me. I don't see how to create an authorization URI (it looks like a big jumbled mess, I'm not sure how one exactly creates one like that), and how to create the JWT token. Does it involve running the code that is listed on that github page?

Comment: I made an oauth url based on the information presented on the "obtaining consent" page. However, the page for creating the JWT token appears to no longer exist.

Comment: Hi. From your own code at the top of your question: you could use this line **oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)**  to get the url, and then **print(oauth_login_url)** print it out. For example, if your redirect_uri is http://localhost:8080, then you will get something like https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=signature%20impersonation&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8080

Comment: I added the oauth_login_url, and when I print it, it appears to be generating one with no issues. However, I am still getting a 'bad request' error. I have put the details in the main post. I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. :/

Comment: Hi, @JCoder96 I didn't notice one thing before. It seems that your envelope_definition isn't configured correctly too. You created a envelope_definition object but didn't put parameters, like recipients to it. Please read my code example carefully above and also make sure you put correct parameters to other objects.

Comment: Added the recipient information, adjusted the location of the envelope definition. My error still appears to be the same.

Comment: I also tried implementing a code in a similar structure to your's (using function calls), and I still get stuck at the same spot. It throws a bad request error when the commmand **api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)** is run. Does this indicate anything blatantly wrong with my code? Or is this a docusign-side error?

Comment: @JCoder96 Hi, I debug your code and did some modifications. I tested it and it  works. Please see the edited answer and read all the comments. Besides, about the **oauth_login_url**, please make sure you open the url in the browser and visit it at least one time to make approval. Also, Please notice that **oauth_login_url** and **oauth_base_url** are different.

Comment: I added the appropriate Redirect URI to my integration key. However, when I hit 'Accept', a page begins to load, but never seems to actually load. This also happens in my application, when I hit the "submit" button, that would send the user to docusign, it begins to load a page, but never actually loads.

Comment: @JCoder96 Is that an another problem that doesn't related to this post? If so, I suggest you to post screenshots (try to include all the information)and modify your question here or open another post so I could take a look of your problems. By the way, did you try the code I provided above to test if you could get the envelope id?

Comment: I saw you asked another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487926/maxretryerror-with-docusign-in-django The problem is you are using the wrong oauth_base_url as  I mentioned before. You need to use **oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com"**.  What you are using is **oauth_login_url**. You need to visit  the oauth_login_url in your browser.

Comment: I'll look into making another post, to see if there's something not relating to the code that I'm doing wrong. I have attempted to visit the oauth_login_url, I still receive a Bad Request when I attempt to go to the oauth_login_url. And the oauth_base_url I have set to "account-d.docusign.com". I'm not using the non-demo base url. I have changed the above code to similar to what you have, and this is the issue I'm getting.

Comment: The error is still occurring at the line **api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)**.

Comment: Have you directly open the oauth_login_url in your browser, like firefox or chrome? Does it prompt a window like https://support.trumpetinc.com/index.php?pg=file&from=2&id=2291 (image found on google)

Comment: I did. And the first time I visited the link, it gave me that. I hit accept, and it was loading the next page without ever actually sending me to another page. Now I don't get that when I try to connect to that link again, I just get a "bad request" error.

Comment: OK. Could you print out the **oauth_base_url** you are using. Also, make sure you add the redirect uri to this page https://screenshots.firefox.com/DqacSfTMvrkkzrSt/admin.docusign.com

Comment: Also, consider using absolute path for private_key_filename

Comment: I'll make the switch to absolute path for private_key_filename. But I've edited my post to show the **oauth_base_url** and **oauth_login_url**, if that helps. And the redirect URI is already added to the integration key.

Comment: For your oauth_base_url, please remove the http:// and only keep oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com" just like my code sample

Comment: Fixed that bit, but I'm still getting the "bad request" error

Comment: hmmm, it seems that it's not the docusign problem if your code is the same as my sample. Does you django in debug mode? Could you setup the logging module for Django so you could see the details of error? By the way, just for reminder, you have some typos below for example, **envelopes_api = Envelopes_Api()** should be **envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi()**, **login_infoi** should be **login_info**

Comment: I fixed the typos, thank you for pointing them out. I probably wouldn't have found them had you not. Alas, I'm still getting bad request errors, but I suppose I should contact support and see if there's anything they can do for me. Thank you very much, for all of your help, Lee.

Comment: No problem. just add the solution to your question if you get it.  For my last advice, you could try to set django DEBUG = True or add ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] to your settings file to see if there is something wrong with django.

Comment: Hello @lee , I hope you are doing well.

So, I almost have my application working with the Docusign API. I've gotten past all of the bad requests, and it appears everything is working. However, when I attempt to send the request via email, the recipient never receives the email requesting the signature. Is this because I don't have a notification set up? And, if so, how do I properly do that? I read through the github, and I still don't quite understand how to define one...